# Convert an ArrayList to an unmodifiable ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to get a unmodifiable ArrayList to a final variable EX_FIELDS. exList is an existing ArrayList object.

```
EX_FIELDS = (ArrayList<String>) Collections.unmodifiableList(exList);
```

This code is present in a static block.When the class loads, I get the following error.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList
```

I need to use the EX_FIELDS to support random access.Is there any other way to accomplish it?Thanks for any help in advance

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`EX_FIELDS` should have type `List<String>`, not `ArrayList<String>`, and you shouldn't need to do any cast: you should just write

```
EX_FIELDS = Collections.unmodifiableList(exList);
```

This is one instance of the much more general rule that you should program to the interface, not the implementation.

Comment: Or perhaps `RandomAccessList`, if that's relevant--the static method does preserve the distinction.

Comment: I am trying to use the list for regular random access,so thought it would be efficient

Comment: @amudhan3093 Use the `List` interface.  Trust the implementation.  This is the best practice.

Answer (score 3):

You get a ClassCastException because `Collections.unmodifiableList()` doesn't return an ArrayList, it returns a `List<T>` (interface) which can be any backing class that implements the List interface.  As you can see from the exception, it is *actually* returning an `UnmodifiableRandomAccessList`.

When you create the variable `EX_FIELDS` you should declare it like

```
List<String> EX_FIELDS = new ArrayList<>();
```

That is, EX_FIELDS is a *List* and you have chosen an *ArrayList* for the actual instance.  Later on you'll do

```
EX_FIELDS = Collections.unmodifiableList(exList);
```

`unmodifiableList()` returns a *List*, but you don't care what kind it *actually* is, as long as it conforms to the *List* interface.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are correct, but missing a crucial point: an unmodifiable list created this way can still be modified.

This call to the Collections class creates a**wrapper** object that wraps around the provided *exList* argument.

In other words: when exList changes, your wrapped list changes as well.

So when you want to be really sure, you have to first create a new temporary list to which you add all entries of *exList*; and then you use that Collections method to wrap around that temporary copy.

Comment: So should i pass it as EX_FIELDS = Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<String>(exList)); so that now reference is maintained?

Comment: I think so (but I am not 100 percent sure if that ArrayList constructor will really create a copy... So, if you want to be sure, just check out the sources). Nice question BTW.

Answer (score 0):

The reason error occurs is `Collections.unmodifiablelist(exList)` returns a List, what you are trying to do is

```
ArrayList<T> EX_FIELDS=(ArrayList<T>)List<T>();
```

List is an interface and cannot be instantiated. The EX_FIELDS variable can only store ArrayList object, hence the classcast exception error.

A proper way to do this is :

```
List<String> EX_FIELDS=Collections.unmodifiablelist(exList)
```